# Setting up SSL with node.js

Tags: node.js

I bought an SSL certificate at GoDaddy and I'm using the following node.js server to attempt to set it up:

```
var https = require('https'),      // module for https
    fs =    require('fs');         // required to read certs and keys

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/example.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/example.com.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/gd_bundle.crt'),
    requestCert:        true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    if (req.client.authorized) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"approved"}');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(401, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"denied"}');
    }
}).listen(443);
```

After running the server, I attempted to visit the website at https://example.com and I just get

```
{"status":"denied"}
```

I guess this is working properly since I'm getting a response, but I think my understanding of how SSL works is wrong.  I thought the browser gets the certificate from the server, which then authenticates it against root certs, i.e. from GoDaddy.  so shouldn't i get

```
{"status":"approved"}
```

just simply visiting https://example.com ?

So I guess my question is, how do I visit https://example.com and get {"status":"approved"}?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting denied, is because you are trying to authenticate using client certificate authentication.  Each end user needs a client certificate signed by your server certificate.  [How to setup Client Certificates](http://blog.nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi) and [Certificate Auth with Node](http://blog.nategood.com/nodejs-ssl-client-cert-auth-api-rest).

If you are just attempting to encrypt your web traffic, you don't need the client certificates.  Use the example here http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/https.html if you just want the traffic encrypted.

Comment: Here's a zero-config example for using trusted peer (client) certificates: https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-ssl-trusted-peer-example

Comment: And a "normal ssl", zero-config example that runs all on its own, so you can be confident that replacing your certs for the dummies included will work for you: https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-ssl-example

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
ca: fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/gd_bundle.crt')
```

`ca` needs to be an array of strings or buffers containing individual certificates. If you supply a bundle, only the first certificate is used and the rest is ignored.

See also: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener

Answer (score 0):

1.) First Open your cpanel
2.) SSL/TLS
3.)Manage SSL sites.
4.) Select Domain on which you want to add ssl
5.) Then Autofill by certificate

You will get here crt and key
create 2 files domain.pem and domain.crt

put crt code into domain.crt and key code into domain.pem file
and put both file on the main root

```
const https = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');


const httpsOptions = {
key: fs.readFileSync('domain.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('domain.crt'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('domain.crt'),
passphrase: '??'
}

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  if (req.client.authorized) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": 
    "application/json"});
    res.end('{"status":"approved"}');
  } else {
    res.writeHead(401, {"Content-Type": 
    "application/json"});
    res.end('{"status":"denied"}');
  }
}).listen(443);
```