# Issued CA causing TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA. Why?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

On the server, I'm initializing the SSLContext with my private key, the certfile provided by the CA that I'm loading from the caroot.crt file. Now, when I initialize this with something like node, everything works fine (for example: [Setting up SSL with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804168/setting-up-ssl-with-node-js)). My intentions were to set everything up the same way. My assumption is that during the handshake, the server is providing the client with a CA, just like my node server would. It seems like that's not the case. What am I doing wrong?

If ssl.CERT_REQUIRED isn't used, everything works perfectly, but I'm wanting to validate that the endpoint (server) is who they say they are.

```
# Server
import socket
import ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile='./path/to/certfile.crt', 
    keyfile='./path/to/keyfile.pem')
context.load_verify_locations('./path/to/caroot.crt')
context.set_default_verify_paths()

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('', 23000))
server_socket.listen(socket.SOMAXCONN)

def handle_client(ssl_socket):
    data = ssl_socket.read()
    while data:
        print("%s" % (str(data)))
        data = ssl_socket.read()

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    ssl_client_socket = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
    handle_client(ssl_client_socket)

# Client
import socket
import ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
# I'm assuming this is not necessary, but I'd like to load the system provided CAs
context.set_default_verify_paths()
# Require CA validation to prevent MITM.
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_client = context.wrap_socket(client_socket)
ssl_client.connect(('', 23000))
ssl_client.send(bytes('hello, world!', 'UTF-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my CA provided 3 different crt files. My solution was to append them in a specific order to generate the correct CA chain that was being passed to `context.load_verify_locations`.

For anyone using COMODO as a provider, here is a blog post: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/04/04/installing-comodo-positive-ssl-certs-on-apache-and-openssl/

Granted, that post is Apache specific, the premise is still the same. The command in question is:

```
cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt  > yourdomain.com.cer
```

You then do:

```
context.load_verify_locations('yourdomain.com.cer')
```

Everything now works as expected.